# apache camel - call an external web service

Tags: web-services, rest, exception, apache-camel

I would like to send an http post to an external web service that I need to call.

```
<from uri="cxfrs://http://localhost:9876?resourceClasses=MyResource"/>
            <log message="Received. " loggingLevel="INFO" logName="MyLogger"/>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                 <constant>POST</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
                <constant>application/json</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setBody>
                <simple>param1=param1value&amp;param2=param2value</simple>
            </setBody>
<to uri="http://samplesample.com?bridgeEndpoint=true" />
<log message="body is ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="MyLogger"/>
```

I'm getting an exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://samplesample.com with statusCode: 400
```

It works fine when I launch a request using rest client.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well according to the error you are not sending the correct syntax. Download wireshark do a packet sniff on both the rest client call and the camel call and compare it. I am sure that the two calls are different and you need to identify why.

Answer (score 2):

camel-cxfrs consumer will turn the REST request into a method call, so the camel-http producer may not interpreter the message rightly.

If you want to proxy REST request by using camel, you can just use camel-jetty component to do that.

```
from("jetty://http://localhost:9876?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
                    .to("http://samplesample.com?throwExceptionOnFailure=false&bridgeEndpoint=true");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your request parameters to the message body you should set the appropriate headers, e.g. for adding HTTP querying parameters use

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpQuery">
 <constant>param1=param1value&amp;param2=param2value</constant>
</setHeader>
```

or for adding HTTP path parameters use

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath">
 <constant>/param1/20</constant>
</setHeader>
```